# trouble with understanding independent events

Tags: probability, probability-theory

In the experiment of rolling a die, event E is getting an even number and event M is getting 1 or prime numbers. So

$$E=\{2,4,6\},\,M=\{1,2,3,5\} \text{ and } P(E)=\frac{1}{2},\, P(M)=\frac{2}{3}$$

Now I am interested in the probability that a single toss of die comes up with both E and M ie;(an even and prime number):

$$P(EM)=P\{2\}=\frac{1}{6}$$

What I find difficult to grasp is E and M are independent (in my mind atleast), so

$$P(EM)=P(E)\cdot P(M)=\frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{2}{3} =\frac{1}{3}$$

This is obviously wrong but can someone show me why E & M are NOT independent ? How does event E affect event M ?

Comment: The events are not independent; independence of events in probability theory is **defined by** $P(A\cap B)=P(A)P(B)$.

Comment: I agree but I am looking for an intuitive reasoning to show they are not independent. Something in terms of how is E affecting M

Comment: E is not affecting M, but our knowing that E happened affects our beliefs that M happened, and this is captured by the concept of dependence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Half of the six numbers on the die are even.  But only $1/4$ of the four numbers on the die that are $1$ or prime are even.  So knowing that the number is $1$ or prime does affect the probability of its being even.

Similarly, $2/3$ of the numbers on the die are $1$ or prime, but only $1/3$ of the even numbers on the die are $1$ or prime, so knowing that the number is 
even affects the probability of its being $1$ or prime.

Comment: Ah .. It makes sense. Thank you. Sorry could not upvote since I do not have enough reputation :(.

Answer (score 2):

> What I find difficult to grasp is E and M are independent (in my mind atleast), so ,...

Why would you think that?   Since only *one from the four* equally-probable outcomes in $M$ is even, as opposed to *three from six* outcomes in total, then would not knowing whether or not the result is in $M$ influence your expectation that the result is in $E$?

That is: $\mathsf P(E\mid M)=1/4, \mathsf P(E)=3/6.$

So $\mathsf P(E\cap M) ~{= \mathsf P(E\mid M)\,\mathsf P(M) \\= \tfrac 14\cdot\tfrac 23 \\= \tfrac 16}$

Answer (score 0):

For an independent event, the probability of it occurring isn't affected by the other event. Thus:

$$P(A | B) = P(A)$$

(That is probability of A happening given that B occurred is the same as probability of A). It's fairly obvious that:

$$P(A|B) = \frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)} $$

So:
$$\frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)} = P(A)$$

And multiplying by P(B)

$$P(A\cap B) = P(A)P(B)$$

And now if we divide by P(A) it's also obvious that P(B|A) = P(B).

To give an intuitive explanation. If the number is even, the chance of it also being a prime is different than if it was randomly selected.